# Call event from native WebSocket to Socket.IO server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, handshake

I have this socket.io server:

```
var io = require('C:\\Program files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\socket.io').listen(55555);
io.set('destroy upgrade', false);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('sayHello', function () {
    console.log('Hello client!');
    socket.emit('sayHello');
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('Goodbye!');
  });
});
```

And I want to connect to the server using the WebSocket class like this:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:55555');
```

I get the connection, but I want to know how can I call an event of the server, example: "sayHello", is that possible? or does Socket.IO use some kind of token in order to avoid spoofing? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [socket.io-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) module directly from node. It handles the socket.io protocol and everything for you, just like the browser, except in node.